# jQuery: Grouping Similar Items

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I'm trying to group similar items in a list. Here's what I'm trying to do. Given a list like the following:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Item #1</li>
    <li class="foo">Item #2</li>
    <li class="foo">Item #3</li>
    <li class="bar">Item #4</li>
    <li class="bar">Item #5</li>
    <li class="foo">Item #6</li>
    <li class="foo">Item #7</li>
    <li class="bar">Item #8</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to end up with the following:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">Item #1 <a>2 More Like This</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="foo">Item #2</li>
            <li class="foo">Item #3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">Item #4</li>
    <li class="bar">Item #5</li>
    <li class="foo">Item #6 <a>1 More Like This</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="foo">Item #7</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="bar">Item #8</li>
</ul>
```

In short, anytime there's 2 or more items with class="foo", they should be grouped together up until reaching a non-class="foo" item. I can then use a link to show or hide the grouped items.

Comment: The end result is the first in each group is visible, and has a new anchor tag attached to toggle the visibility of the rest of the group. I've managed to write some code that works, but it's a bit convoluted,and I suspect there is a more pure jQuery way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/ipiki3/3/

```
$('ul > li.foo')
    .filter(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        return $th.next('li.foo').length && !$th.prev('li.foo').length;
    })
    .each(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        var len= $th.append('<a href="#"> more like this</a>')
                    .nextUntil(':not(li.foo)').wrapAll('<ul>').length;
        $th.next('ul').appendTo(this);
        $th.children('a').prepend(len);
    });
```

**EDIT:** Fixed a mistake with the `len` variable, and added an example.

---

**Explanation:** What's happening with the `.filter()` is that it is narrowing the `li.foo` elements down to the first in a group *(has at least one `li.foo` after it, and none before)*.

Then with the `.each()` it appends the `<a>`, get's the next elements until it reaches one that is not `li.foo`, wraps those with a `<ul>` and returns how many there were using the `length` property.

Then we traverse over to that new `<ul>` and append it to the first `li.foo` in the group.

Finally we prepend the quantity we stored in the `length` property to the `<a>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I come up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var groups = {}
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var class_name = self.attr('class');
        if (class_name) {
            if (typeof groups[class_name] == 'undefined') {
                groups[class_name] = [];
            }
            groups[class_name].push(self);
        }
    });
    var ul = $('ul');
    ul.empty();
    for (var class_name in groups) {
        var array = groups[class_name];
        ul.append('<li class="' + class_name + '">' + $(array[0]).html() + 
            '<a>More Like this</a><ul></ul>');
        $(array.splice(1)).each(function() {
            ul.find('li.' + class_name + ' ul').append(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use `class` as a variable name. It breaks in some browsers because it is a future reserved word.